# Google Cloud Storage: Is there a limit on the number of projects, buckets, service accounts that can be created?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

In the GCP's Object Storage, is there any limit on the following:

- Buckets that can be created per project
- Projects that can be created
- Number of service accounts that can be created per project

If yes, how much is the limit for each of the above mentioned items.

Answer (score 2):

- Buckets per project: No limit
- Number of projects: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
- Service Accounts per project: 100, but it can be raised if you are a paying customer and ask for it ([link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/support#what_is_the_maximum_number_of_service_accounts_i_can_have_in_a_project))

Comment: Any idea yet what the limit on # of projects is?

Comment: @JDOaktown Google does not disclose the exact number, only that 
"_If you have fewer than 30 projects remaining in your quota, a notification displays the number of projects remaining in your quota on the New Project page_" ([link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#number_of_projects)). 

I would assume you can ask for a quota increase, similarly how you can ask for more service accounts.

Comment: Yes, I asked for and received a quota increase of 50 projects.  But I think knowing what the precise limit is is important.  Pretty Lame that GCP doesn't make that info available.  The whole aspect of project limits is hinky.